# C++ Array with while loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Hi guys please check this code. I want to create a program in which I will be prompted to enter first name and last name then output it in chronological order without having to create variable for each first name and last name.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

int fname[9];
int lname[9];
int x;

while (x < 10){
    cout<<"Enter first name: ";
    cin>>fname[0];
    cout<<"Enter last name: ";
    cin>>lname[0];
    x = x + 10;
}

x = 0;

while (x < 10){
    cout<<fname[0]<<" "<<lname[0]<<"\n";
    x = x + 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `int` arrays for text input?

Comment: `while (x<10){ /*...*/ x = x+10;}` will execute exactly once. Also the second `while` loop is broken: You write the same stuff 10 times.

Comment: so string fname[0] = ""; then how about for the loop? I need to store data sequentially and then print it after.

Comment: @nyelnyelnyel Just start with a `std::vector<std::string>>` and please dont abuse `while` loops when a simple `for` loop would be much clearer

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays should be type strings, rest of the code should look like this:

```
for(int x=0;x<10;x++) {
    cout<<"Enter first name: ";
    cin>>fname[x];
    count<<"Enter last name: ";
    cin>>lname[x];
}
for(x=0;x<10;x++){
    cout<<fname[x]<<" "<<lname[x]<<"\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

In your own snippet you're printing the first element of your arrays 10 times, this will print the x-th element while x goes from 0 to 9.

Comment: I can't print the names. The program lags after I input the names. "Untitled1.exe has stopped working"

Comment: Can you post the code you're using as this is only a snippet that I posted.